# How to search all the content in jquery mobile collapsible listview with only one searchbar (inner listview data also)

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

[Collapsible list jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Vg4z/)

here in this link when i search internal data it only search upper list heading
but is it, possible that when i type in above example's search bar (example : internal data like :-"`Acura`") so it shows only "`Acura`" in jquery mobile?

```
<html><head></head><body><div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="outer-ul">
            <li>
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="c">
                    <h3>Firs Collapsed list</h3>
                    <ul data-role="listview">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Acura</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Audi</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">BMW</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="c">
                    <h3>Second Collapsed list</h3>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-theme="d">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Cadillac</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Chrysler</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Dodge</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this : http://jsbin.com/ogexof/18

This is the same as you want.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you!  I had to make some changes to make it work with jQuery 1.9 and above:  http://jsbin.com/IlaQEfI/2/  (There may be a better way to do it.)